Unable to access Response cookies in NextJS middleware
I'm having trouble accessing the cookies of a Response object in NextJS middleware.
From my understanding, when a login is successful at the /api/auth/login endpoint, it sets a cookie on the Response. I'm trying to retrieve that Response using NextResponse.next in the middleware and check the cookie.
However, when I try to access the cookie using response.cookies.get('token') or headers.get('Set-Cookie') in the middleware, it returns undefined or null. On the other hand, when I directly check the Response at the API call site, I can see that the cookie is set correctly.
I think I might be misunderstanding how middleware works in NextJS. If there is a correct way to access the Response cookies in NextJS middleware, please let me know. Also, if I'm misunderstanding the behavior of middleware, please advise me on what parts I should modify.
Result:
 POST /api/auth/login 200 in 12080ms
response.cookies.get('token') undefined
headers.get('Set-Cookie') null
 POST /login 303 in 16313ms
response.cookies.get('token') undefined
headers.get('Set-Cookie') null

Here are the code examples:
./middleware.ts:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { parse } from 'cookie';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: request.headers,
    },
  });
  const token1 = response.cookies.get('token');
  console.log("response.cookies.get('token')", token1)
  const { headers } = response;
  const token2 = headers.get('Set-Cookie');
  console.log("headers.get('Set-Cookie')", token2)

  return response;
}

./app/api/auth/login/route.ts

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { fetchUser } from '@/lib/data';


export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const { email, pnum } = await request.json();
  const pnum_matches = pnum.match(/[Pp]?(\d{1,})/);

  if (!pnum_matches) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Invalid participant number' }, { status: 400 });
  }
  
  const pnum_match = pnum_matches[1];
  const secretKey = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

  if (!secretKey) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' }, { status: 500 });
  }
  
  const user = await fetchUser(email, pnum_match);

  if (user && user.length > 0) {
    const token = jwt.sign({ email, pnum }, secretKey, { expiresIn: '3h' });
    const response = NextResponse.json({ message: 'Authentication successful' }, { status: 200 });

    response.cookies.set({
      name: 'token',
      value: token,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      maxAge: 60 * 60,
      path: '/',
    });
    return response;
  } else {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Authentication failed' }, { status: 401 });
  }
}

Thank you.

To be honest, I'm a bit confused by your use case. Doesn't you supposed to access cookies by using cookies().get('token') on your route handler ? And why you're trying to access route handler response from the middleware ?

@cantdocpp
My goal is to store the cookie from an API response in the client's browser when making a request from a Next.js Server Action. However, the API response reaches the server instead of the client, so the cookie doesn't make it to the browser.
I thought I could handle this in the middleware by accessing the API response cookies there, but it didn't work. It seems I misunderstood how middleware works in Next.js.
I'm curious if there's a way to properly handle this scenario, either by accessing the API response cookies in the middleware or using an alternative approach.

Okay, but i don't see you setting any cookies in your API Route handler. Have you tried cookies().set("token", token) in your LOGIN API Route handler ?

@cantdocpp Yeah, but it doesn't work.
